# Discord Bot command wont do anything Ive tried to fix it but couldnt figure it out

Tags: discord.js

this command at the moment does absolutely nothing can anyone help me

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example)
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'cute') {
    const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();


    message.channel.send(`${taggedUser.username} is a cutie`);
};
```

I know if chains are messy im gonna update it in a bit

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to be able to help you. Have you tried logging `taggedUser`?

Comment: Sorry im fairly new to this stuff how do i log something?

Comment: `console.log();` Docs for this are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: I've trying logging it and no information came, Whenever i try to use the command nothing happens idk how else to describe it

Comment: Then you need to post a full example of your code in order for us to see what could be going wrong

Comment: There ive updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a syntax error in your code, as you never close the `else if` statement. You should also have an `else` statement to account for the command not being found, or you could even use a `switch` as it is faster.

You're also missing a `'` on one of your statements too.

A fix is:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'example') {
        message.channel.send('example');
    } else if (command === 'cute') {
        const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send(`${taggedUser.username} is a cutie`);
    } else {
        message.channel.send('command not found');
    }
};
```